# Which is the nearest town to saskatoon(SK) for economic living?

Tags: canada, resident-permit, residency

I have a plan to move to saskatchewan(CANADA) with PR status.

I would be moving alone to Saskatchewan and my family members would be joining me after my job settlement. I would prefer sharing accomodation that costs not more than 300 CAD per month.

On regular basis, I would be attending job interviews in saskatoon.

I would like to know the town that is nearest(less expensive) from saskatoon, in less than 150 KM radius.

My whole intent to stay in nearest town is to avail reasonable rental price for accomodation and maintain less cost of living. I can manage to travel by road everyday.

Please help me!!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Saskatoon is fairly small town (pop. 220K), with no other towns of size anywhere nearby.  I don't think you will be able to get a meaningfully lower rent by driving even 150 km.

Also, please bear in mind that:

1. Gas in Canada costs about $1/liter, so there is a significant cost to driving that far
2. Winter driving can be very slow and dangerous, particularly if you are not used to it

Comment: "there is a significant cost to driving that far" - unless you are coming from (say) the UK where it's 2.23 CAD/liter, so will seem cheap.

Comment: Per their other posts, OP is from India -- although, to my mild surprise, gas there is more expensive than Canada!  (Around Rs 65/ltr, or C$1.20.)

Comment: Saskatchewan has oil reserves.india buys oil from Saudi Arabia.USA buys oil more from sask than Kuwait.

Comment: @jpatokal You seem to be from IT sector. Am moving to SK with html/css/javascript-angularjs. Do you think there are enough jobs on these technologies as front end web developer?

Comment: @overexchange Sorry, no idea.